# How do you limit the number of files you want to view using winscp?

Tags: winscp

Is there anyway to load only selected number of files using winscp .. there are more than 50000 files which hangs my winscp!

Comment: So if you limit them, how will you edit the right ones? Looks like you have another problem. You'd better get the files organized or just avoid that folder.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue faced by a few users and there doesn't seem to be a way to fix it. You might try one or more of the following:

- When logging in, uncheck the option to `Resolve symbolic links` under `Environment > Directories` <sup>[[doc]](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_directories#directory_reading_options)</sup>
- Under `Preferences > Transfer`, uncheck the `Calculate total size` option <sup>[[doc]](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom#calculate)</sup>
- Try the [command line](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting)
- Not entirely sure about this one and whether it even makes sense in your case, but you might also try excluding/including certain file-types.<sup>[[doc]](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom#other)</sup>

References:

- https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8379
- https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4215

Comment: With SFTP, one can also press `Esc` key while directory is loading to abort it.

Comment: I've had this issue when I opened Winscp and it tried to list a directory with previously few files but now a lot. `Esc` key did the trick for me.